# Mathematica, define multiple functions using for loop

Tags: for-loop, wolfram-mathematica, user-defined-functions

I am using usual for-loop for computation in Mathematica:

`For[i=1,i<n+1,i++,  ...calculation... ]`

For each `i` I need to define a function `F_i[x_,y_]:=...`. Here "i" is suuposed to be a label of the function. This is however not the corrcet Mathematica expression.

The question is, how to define multiple functions distinguished by the label i? I mean, what is the correct syntax?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I have some confidence that the for loop is not the way to go in Mathematica.  Mathematica already has pattern matching that likely eliminates the need for the loop.

What about something like this

```
f[i_][x_,y_]:= i(x+y)
```

or something like this

```
f[s_String][x_,y_]:=StringLength[s](x+y)
```

or even

```
f[s_,x_,y_]:=StringLength[s](x+y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps which may help. There are two versions below, the second one includes the value of `i` on the RHS of the function definition.

```
n = 2;

For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++,
 f[i][x_, y_] := (x + y)*i]

?f
```

Global`f

f[1][x_,y_] := (x+y) i

f[2][x_,y_] := (x+y) i

```
Clear[i]

f[2][2, 3]
```

5 i

```
Quit[]

n = 2;

For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++,
 With[{j = i},
  f[i][x_, y_] := (x + y)*j]]

?f
```

Global`f

f[1][x$*,y$*] := (x$+y$) 1

f[2][x$*,y$*] := (x$+y$) 2

```
Clear[i]

f[2][2, 3]
```

10